# Conditions in render option [material-table]

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, material-table

I am using material-table(https://material-table.com/#/) and I need to change the icon in a column according to its value. Is it possible to do it in the render option:

```
render: rowData => (
    <div>
        <i className="far fa-map-marker"></i>
        <span>{rowData.locationName}</span>
    </div>
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with:

```
render: rowData => (
    <div>
        <i className={`far ${rowData.value === someValue ? "first-icon" : "second-icon"}` }></i>
        <span>{rowData.locationName}</span>
    </div>
)
```

If there are more options I would suggest going with:

```
const valueToIconMap = { someValue: "first-icon", anotherValue: "second-icon", ...more values }
...somecode...
render: rowData => {
    return <div>
        <i className={`far ${valueToIconMap[rowData.value]}`}></i>
        <span>{rowData.locationName}</span>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understand what you want correctly but heres what I can assume you want:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import { Add, Delete } from '@material-ui/icons'

function App(props) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");

    const test = [<Add/>,<Delete/>];

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {test.map(e => { return e })}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```